# Fancybox issues after installation

Tags: fancybox

I'm using Fancybox v4 and have setup the css and js according to installation guide, but still my image opens as if no Fancybox is present.

I'm no wiz on these things, so I hope someone can help me out :-)

The site I'm working on is locates at https://new.bigbox8700.dk/
It's the image in the "PRAKTISK INFORMATION" section.

Regards
Thomas

Comment: Please do a screenshot of the problematic part of your website, instead of giving a link. Who knows what is behind a link?

Comment: I see it works now. If you wonder why your page is jumping, then it is because your `<html>` element has `style="overflow-y: auto;"` and you also have `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Comment: Thank you both, I'll remember the screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging I found out that your JavaScript file `js-18a51-27218.js` contains Mootools v1.4.5 (released 10 years ago!) and, unfortunately, Mootools changes global objects and that breaks Fancybox. It's amazing that you're using 10-year-old Mootools and 6-year-old jQuery at the same time on the new project.

Since MooTools is causing this problem and has not been updated for 6 years, it is recommended that you remove it.

Comment: Thank you!
I'm using Joomla, so I guess it's added there - I will get it removed!